# How to convert Scala List[String] to legacy Java List<?>

Tags: java, scala, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have legacy (no modification allowed) Java code:

```
//File Foo.java
package sof;
public interface Foo<T> {}

//File Bar.java
package sof;
public class Bar implements Foo<String> {}

//File Holder.java    
package sof;
import java.util.List;
public class Holder {
    private List<Foo<?>> lst;
    public Holder() {}
    public Holder(List<Foo<?>> lst) {this.lst = lst;}
    public List<Foo<?>> getLst() {return lst;}
    public void setLst(List<Foo<?>> lst) {this.lst = lst;}
}
```

Now, in my Scala code I want to pass List of **bars** to **holder**:

```
import sof._
import collection.JavaConverters._
val bar = new Bar()
val bars: java.util.List[Bar] = List(bar).asJava
val holder = new sof.Holder(bars)
```

It won't compile. The error is:

> Error:(37, 18) type mismatch; found   : java.util.List[**sof.Bar**]
>   required: java.util.List[**sof.Foo[_]**] Note: sof.Bar <: sof.Foo[_], but
>   Java-defined trait List is invariant in type E. You may wish to
>   investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: sof.Foo[_]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
>   new sof.Holder(bars)

As a workaround, I can

```
val holder = new sof.Holder()
val tmpLst = holder.getLst
tmpLst.add(bar)
```

It works but it's awful.
So, what's the Scala structure that fits `java.util.List<?>`?

Comment: The problem is not converting the **Scala** `List` into the **Java** one. You already have that. The problem is that because **Java** doesn't provide control over _variance_ a `j.u.List<Bar>` is not a subtype of a `j.u.List<Foo<?>>`. You may try the up casting before the call to `asJava` something like this should work: `val bars = (List(bar) : List[String]).asJava`

Comment: You don't have any `java.util.List<?>` in your code or error.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Unfortunately, it ends up with "Cannot upcast List[Bar] to List[String]" compilation error. And yes, it makes sense: indeed, a list of Bar is not a list of String.

Comment: @Lopotun O, sorry a typo, I was in mobile. It should have been `val bars = (List(bar) : List[Foo[String]]).asJava` Because a **Bar** is **Foo[String]**.

Comment: @Jasper-M I'm afraid I didn't quite understand your answer. The given Java code is legacy and I cannot change it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks for your answer. Now there is the the same problem but now on the construction level: 
Error:(44, 18) type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[sof.Foo[String]]
 required: java.util.List[sof.Foo[\_]]
Note: sof.Foo[String] <: sof.Foo[\_], but Java-defined trait List is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: sof.Foo[_]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  new sof.Holder(bars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java wants `java.util.List<Foo<?>>` but you are giving it `java.util.List<Bar>`. Java does not support `List` variance so this does not work.

You need to give it the actual type it wants:

```
val bar = new Bar()
val foos: List[Foo[_]] = List(bar)
val holder = new sof.Holder(foos.asJava)
```

Comment: Same (almost) error. Now it won't cast sof.Foo[String] to sof.Foo[_]
Error:(45, 38) type mismatch;
found   : java.util.List[sof.Foo[String]]
required: java.util.List[sof.Foo[_]]
Note: sof.Foo[String] <: sof.Foo[_], but Java-defined trait List is invariant in type E.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: sof.Foo[_]`. (SLS 3.2.10)
  val holder = new sof.Holder(foos.asJava)

Comment: @Lopotun Are you sure you have `foos: List[Foo[_]]` and not `foos: List[Foo[String]]`? That would produce the error message you show.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Bingo! Yes, you're right. It was my typos and List[Foo[\_]] works perfectly. Now, it's my turn to understand why and how it works :-)

Comment: @Lopotun It wasn't your typo, the answer was updated after your first comment so you were correct at the time. Jasper-M helpfully updated the answer to the correct one after your comment.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I see it now. It works and it's the main thing. And I learned that I should revise answers: they may be changed :-)